# Let $s = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + ... (|q|<1)$ and $S = 1 + Q + Q^2 + Q^3 + ... (|Q|<1)$. Then sum $1 + qQ + q^2Q^2 + q^3Q^3+...$ is equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone give me some hint for this task.I know those two are geometric sequence but I don't know how to even start solving this. Solution is $$\frac{sS}{s + S -1}$$

Comment: Compute things in terms of $\frac{1}{s},\,\frac{1}{S}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$s=\frac1{1-q}\implies q=1-\frac1s$$
$$S=\frac1{1-Q}\implies Q=1-\frac1S$$

$$1+qQ+q^2Q^2+\ldots=\frac1{1-qQ}=\ldots$$